# Bash expansion repeat a string n to n times

Tags: bash

I'm trying to find combinations of characters that fit a (c)v pattern for up to n syllables, and so started by using expansion like `echo {,p,t}{a,i}` for all the possibilities for one syllable (using just 2 letters for readability). In order to get more syllables, all I could think of was expanding it for each syllable like `echo {{,p,t}{a,i},{,p,t}{a,i}{,p,t}{a,i}}` (ie, 'all the one syllable combinations then all the two syllable combinations'). Is there a better way to extend this to n syllables, so that I can type something kinda like `echo {,p,t}{a,i}*{1..3}` for all the 1, 2, and 3 syllable expansions(and so on)?

Comment: Bash seems to be a very inadequate tool for what you're trying to do. Have you considered not using a shell language, which is really meant to serve computer administration tasks, for problems like generating strings of syllables?

Comment: I don't know any shell languages, I am relatively new to the command line; that's why I started with my problem rather than how I've tried to solve it so far. I presume that means that there isn't a repeat n times format for bash expansion? Does that just not come up often enough to be considered a useful feature?

Comment: Bash scripting is a shell language. That's why I asked you to consider whether you really want to do it in such an ill-suited language! I don't think there's a direct way, no. When would that problem ever come up in administrating computers? That's what bash is for: starting other programs and allowing for automation of simple Administrator tasks. You could possibly hack something together with recursive replacements in a generated list, but that is hard to program, harder to understand and unnecessarily error-prone. Question: do you know any other programming languages?

Comment: ahh, I see. I thought shell language would mean making a .sh file and running it; that means a .sh file is basically for running each line in bash? I have used a number of other programming languages, but I defaulted to bash since I can just open up the terminal and just run things to get answers to my questions, where I'd have to get something else to run other code. also, if repeating isn't helpful, why is brace expansion helpful? aren't they almost the same thing?

Comment: Can I get an example of the desired output you'd want for `n=3`, to ensure that my program is up to your specifications? Want to make sure I understand the requirements adequately.

Comment: it's nothing so specific, mostly just to satisfy my curiosity. I was playing around with it to see what kinds of combinations produce different things; the exact format of the output doesn't matter. I mostly just wanted the data to mess around with; for example I was also piping it through `sed` and `wc -w` to see how many of some pattern showed up or other things like that.

Comment: A case where brace expansion is very useful is when you want to create a folder for each day of the month, 1..31. How often do you need to create a folder for each pineapple, pineappapple, pineapplelele...?

Comment: The "I need to get the tools I need installed" argument is a bit flimsy: every significant desktop Linux these days comes with interpreters for multiple languages installed. Try running python or perl! Installing Lua, a C++ compiler or JavaScript runtime is also but a single command away. And just like your she'l script is just your shell being called with the file as argument (that's why they have #!/bin/bash at the beginning! It specifies which program to run with the file), so is e.g. a python script just being executed when you run `python scriptname.py`. No magic involved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 165 bytes

```bash
f(){
i=$1
exp=$2
con=$2
printf '{'
while [ "$i" -gt 0 ] ; do
  (( i-- ))
  printf '%s' "$con,"
  con+=$exp
done
printf '}'
echo
}

eval echo "$(f 6 '{,p,t}{a,i}')"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3NCgIhHMTv/6cYxFBJoTp0iX2S6LDtaissq7RSgfjsZkSd5gPmN9d@nWp1UmXyHd@TfcWO8QOjISxfE@9@SQ4iC3pOfrY4g3uYW8IOF5wwBgKkhDcGSjX/G2xWAcYbR7PWNt12vOFpDIv9U4sgO0yBCpF99DM@AVw6HNujjjqV3GtfhCKq9Q0)

Comment: Lol love that you used the code golf template

Comment: It served the purpose I needed it to 

Comment: And I honestly think that's one valid way of how solving this kind of problem in bash could be considered — a mental sport, but not something you'd want to see for production usage

Comment: I love it :). (Useful to try it without eval :).)

Answer (score 0):

*Usind the most of your code/logic.*

## [ksh](http://kornshell.com/), 95 bytes, no evil `eval` :)

```
n=4
for ((i=1; i<=n; i++)) {
    printf -v x '{,p,t}{a,i}%.0s' {1..$i}
    printf '%s\n' $x
}
```

If your `ksh` implementation don't support `printf -v x`, replace by `x=$(printf ...)`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy7O@P8/z9aEKy2/SEFDI9PW0Foh08Y2D0hqa2tqKlRzKQBBha2KRkFRZl5JmoJ6tU6BTkltdaJOZq2qnkGxukK1oZ6eSmatJlglTJVqcUyeuoJKBVctF9f//wA)

Comment: Note that assumes recent versions of ksh93u+m for `printf -v`. `-v` is not really necessary in ksh93 since you can do `x=${ printf ....;}` instead.

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 73 bytes

```sh
c=('' p t) v=(a i) r=({1..4})
(){echo ${(e)@}} '${(el['$^r'*6][$^c$^v])}'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/2VZDXV2hQKFEU6HMViNRIVNTochWo9pQT8@kVpNLQ7M6NTkjX0GlWiNV06G2VkEdxMqJVleJK1LXMouNVolLVokri9WsVf//HwA)

Unrolling it:

```sh
$ c=( '' p t ) v=( a i ) r=( {1..4} )
$ echo $c$v
p ta i
$ echo $^c$^v
a i pa pi ta ti
```

With `$^c` instead of `$c`, arrays are expanded a bit like in brace expansion.

```sh
$ echo ${(l[12][$^c$^v])}
$^c$^v$^c$^v
```

We expand *nothing* (that parameter expansion has no parameter) using the `l`eft padding operator, here padding with `$^c$^v` strings to a length of `12` (twice the length of `$^c$^v` string).

```sh
$ echo ${(el[12][$^c$^v])}
aa ai apa api ata ati ia ii ipa ipi ita iti paa pai papa papi pata pati pia pii pipa pipi pita piti taa tai tapa tapi tata tati tia tii tipa tipi tita titi
```

If we add the `e` parameter expansion flag, the expansions in the result are `e`valuated/`e`xpanded.

So all we need to do is generate those for paddings of 6, 12, ... n*6.

```sh
$ echo '${(el['$^r'*6][$^c$^v])}'
${(el[1*6][$^c$^v])} ${(el[2*6][$^c$^v])} ${(el[3*6][$^c$^v])} ${(el[4*6][$^c$^v])}
```

If we can put those words in an array, we can apply the `e` flag to it to expand the result. For that we use an anonymous function, and pass those words as arguments, and they'll be available in the `$@` aka `$argv` array within.